# Having trouble running LTC2953-1 simulation on LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I having a hard time in running the simulation for the LTC2953-1 which is a Push Button On/Off Controller IC , it also has other features which i'm not going to use for time being so they are disabled/ not used.

Here i am expecting the output (EN)[Green trace] pin to be latched high as soon as the Switch is pressed at pin (/PB)[Blue trace] for more than 6.4 seconds (1uF is set to have =~ 6.4seconds)where in the simulation it does not work, i hope it's something i've done wrong. Also i am getting this error which maybe the cause of not getting the IC to work properly..
[image]
[image]
[image]

I would really appreciate if someone would point out what might be the cause of this situation .

LTspice project file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a51ff1ea99aff0e7cdffca9bf973e1b820201108200012/6d05fb03ebf874db8be8b8dadc76d95620201108200053/8e2010)

[image]
EDIT1 : Download link updated with a better host.
EDIT2 : I went ahead and put a 100K pullup and set up the switch as per indicated and now it alive but it nearly instantly works at the first falling edge like there is not delay, any idea what could be the culprit ? I'll dig more in the datasheet maybe i missed something.

Comment: All the useful information appears to be 403:Forbidden.

Comment: do you mean the project file is unaccessible ? if so , i've changed download link to a better host. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simulation runs, that's just a warning, not an error. If it bothers you so much, just add `Rpar=1g` to `C1`.

Comment: got it working partially, it latches on nearly without a delay. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sultanpepper This appears to be working correctly, as I see it.  Are you expecting the 6.4 seconds to apply to the turn on?  Datasheet says that turn-on is fixed at 32ms, and PDT (power-down time) capacitor, as the name suggests, only applies to the turn-off time.

Comment: Yes, it all makes sense now. Thank you for pointing that out, i feel embarrassed, lesson learned.